# A replacement for ViewPager on Android 3.1

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm developing an Android 3.1 tablet application.

I've found a really nice widget ViewPager that it is only available on `android.support.v4.view.ViewPager`.

I think I don't have to use `android.support.v4` if I'm using Android 3.1 SDK.

**Do you know if there is something similar to ViewPager on Android 3.1?**
 or 
**How can I use fragments on Android 3.1?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think I don't have to use android.support.v4 if I'm using Android 3.1 SDK.

For `ViewPager`, yes, you do. The Android Support package contains both backports (e.g., fragments) and new stuff (e.g., `ViewPager`).

> Do you if there is something similar to ViewPager on Android 3.1?

`ViewPager` is in the Android Support package, not in any firmware release.

> How can I use fragments on Android 3.1?

You can use [native fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html), if your app will only run on API Level 11+.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can I mix native fragments with ViewPager?

Comment: @VansFannel: Well, technically, `ViewPager` is completely independent of the fragment system. That being said, the two concrete implementations of `PagerAdapter` (`FragmentPagerAdapter` and `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`) are set up to use the Android Support package's fragment backport. However, you could readily clone those adapters out of the source code and modify them to reference the native `Fragment` classes instead of the backport, or roll your own `PagerAdapter` (even one that has nothing to do with fragments at all).

Comment: Thanks again. So, if I want to swipe between pages I have to use ViewPager, isn't it?

Comment: @VansFannel: Well, it's the only thing I know of that truly fits the bill. `HorizontalScrollView` and `Gallery` are also horizontal-scrolling widgets, but they are not really set up for "swipe between pages".